# Switch between users with sudo while running shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have access to group machines (linux-boxes) and I have created users on them.

I need to run some commands which requires sudo.

But rest of the commands has to be run from the user who can't sudo.

How to switch back and fro between users who can sudo and can't ?

**UPDATE**: [Problems with sudo inside expect script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786815/problems-with-sudo-inside-expect-script) The expect script shows a good example.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this so not posting as an answer but have you thought about just using `su` to switch to an unprivelaged user? so run the script as root or using sudo, then in the script, do something like `su user -c command` ? ref: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?su

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're a privileged user with `sudo` (typically a `sudo` group member on debian systems), you can run a command as any other user using:

```
sudo -u nobody ls
```

from sudo's manpage:

```
   -u user     The -u (user) option causes sudo to run the specified command as a user other than root.  To specify a uid instead of a user name, use #uid.
               When running commands as a uid, many shells require that the '#' be escaped with a backslash ('\').  Security policies may restrict uids to
               those listed in the password database.  The sudoers policy allows uids that are not in the password database as long as the targetpw option is
               not set.  Other security policies may not support this.
```

so typically, you may want to create a script that connects as your favorite sudoer, run a few `sudo` commands as root, and all the others as the other user.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` launches another process, shell itself cannot set its UID. So:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo Normal user
id
sudo sh -c '
    echo Root user
    id
    echo More commands as root user...
'
echo Back to normal user
id
```

Be careful with escaping inside the inner shell though.

For just a few commands, you can obviously prefix each command with `sudo`:

```
sudo echo Root user
sudo id
sudo echo More commands as root user...
```

No need to worry about escaping here.