# Problems with sudo inside expect script

Tags: linux, shell, expect, sudo

I am running the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set user [lindex $argv 0]
set pass [lindex $argv 1]
set PATH [lindex $argv 2]
set INV_PATH [lindex $argv 3]

spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@localhost

expect "assword: "
send "$pass\r"
expect "$ "
send "echo $pass | /usr/local/bin/sudo -S $INV_PATH/orainstRoot.sh\r"

expect "$ "
send "cd $PATH/bin\r"

expect "$ "
send "echo $pass | /usr/local/bin/sudo -S cp oraenv coraenv sqlplus dbhome /usr/bin\r"

expect "$ "
send "echo $pass | /usr/local/bin/sudo -S $PATH/root.sh\r"

expect "Check"
send "\r"
```

Its **working fine in some machines** and for some machines its throwing the following error... I have checked, its not the PATH causing the issue.

```
/usr/local/bin/sudo: /scratch/prod_sw/app/oraInventory/orainstRoot.sh: command not found
$ echo PASSWD | /usr/local/bin/sudo -S cd /scratch/prod_sw/app/prod_sw/product/11.2.0/db_home/bin
/usr/local/bin/sudo: cd: command not found
$ echo PASSWD | /usr/local/bin/sudo -S cp oraenv coraenv sqlplus dbhome /usr/bin
cp: cannot stat `oraenv': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `coraenv': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `sqlplus': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat `dbhome': No such file or directory
$ echo PASSWD | /usr/local/bin/sudo -S /scratch/prod_sw/app/prod_sw/product/11.2.0/db_home//root.sh
Check /scratch/prod_sw/app/prod_sw/product/11.2.0/db_home/install/root_slcad22rhu_2013-07-22_04-41-49.log for the output of root script
```

Comment: might be a location of `sudo`, check `which sudo`. On some machines it can be `/usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: `PATH` is not the issue. Location of `sudo` is same in all machines.

Comment: +1 for good example of `expect` with `sudo`. the errors are from the cmd `cp`, right? ... This means that the directory setup is not the same, or some other aspect of the environment on the failing machine is not the same as those on the working machines. You'll have to dig in and investigate. I run into this all the time, where environments are different on machines that are allegedly built to the same spec.  Good luck!

Comment: The error output doesn't match your example script. You show that your script does `send "cd $PATH/bin\r"`, but the output shows `echo PASSWD | /usr/local/bin/sudo -S cd /scratch/prod_sw/app/prod_sw/product/11.2.0/db_home/bin`, indicating that the sent command was not `cd $PATH/bin\r`, but *`echo PASSWORD | /usr/local/bin/sudo -S`* `cd $PATH/bin\r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give complete path for these files and check once.

> cp /path/oraenv /path/coraenv /path/sqlplus /path/dbhome /usr/bin